# Are there plans to make lambda expressions in Java more performant than anonymous classes?

Tags: java, performance, lambda, jvm

When I first heard about lambdas in Java I thought that this was already the case.

However, I later read that [this study](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013kuksen-2014088.pdf) which says that this is not the true.
It says that there are possibilities of improvement but not if improvements will be done.

Comment: Lambdas have a different implementation for which _some_ things are slower, and some are faster, and they're continuing to get optimized further.  (It looks like most things are faster, though, or only a hair slower.)

Comment: Are there concrete plans for improvements?

Comment: The presentation discussed areas that needed improvement; I'm not sure what more you're looking for.

Comment: I've asked wether there will be improvements not if it can be improved.

Comment: People are actively working on finding ways to improve the areas in need of improvement, but that's open-ended work that doesn't necessarily have a well-defined endpoint.

Comment: It's almost certainly better now than it was as of that presentation.  It might have passed the point where it beats anonymous classes, and it might not have; I don't know of up-to-date benchmarks.  It's still being improved.